# How to correct read INI files using GLIB and C code?

Tags: c, ini, glib

I'm trying to correct use GLIB to read ini files, but I still getting memory leak, specially in one of the functions.
I have created some custom functions to read string, int, int64 and float numbers. My code is working, except that I'm getting memory leak from int64 version. Also, in other functions, I'm getting "Still Reachable" records. I'm aware that this second case is not a real problem, it's not a memory leak itself. But I would like to know if there's any way to make this better and clear those reachable records.

About the 'problematic' function, it's this one:

```
long ini_getInteger64(char *ini_file, char *section, char *key, long def_value) {
    GKeyFile *localini;
    GError *error = NULL;
    long abc = 0;

    localini = g_key_file_new();

    if (g_key_file_load_from_file(localini, ini_file, G_KEY_FILE_KEEP_COMMENTS, &error) == FALSE) {
        mylog_log("Error loading ini file.\n");
        g_key_file_free(localini);
        if (error != NULL) {
            g_error_free(error);
        }
        return def_value;
    }

    abc = g_key_file_get_int64(localini, section, key, &error);    
    g_key_file_free(localini);

    if (error != NULL) {        
        if (error->code == G_KEY_FILE_ERROR_KEY_NOT_FOUND || error->code == G_KEY_FILE_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE || error->code == G_KEY_FILE_ERROR_GROUP_NOT_FOUND) {
            g_error_free(error);
            return def_value;
        } else {
            g_error_free(error);
            return abc;
        }
    } else {
        return abc;
    }


}
```

And this is how I'm calling it:

```
long total_packets = ini_getInteger64(f_file, "stats", "total_packets", 0);
```

This is part of valgrind report for this function:

```
==15486== 184 (88 direct, 96 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 70 of 87
==15486==    at 0x6CA177F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==15486==    by 0x72EB8D0: g_malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5800.3)
==15486==    by 0x7303832: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5800.3)
==15486==    by 0x72D3D2D: g_hash_table_new_full (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5800.3)
==15486==    by 0x72BFCF0: g_get_language_names_with_category (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5800.3)
==15486==    by 0x72DB58B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5800.3)
==15486==    by 0x72DD22C: g_key_file_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5800.3)
==15486==    by 0x11AFAC: ini_getInteger64 (utils.c:493)
==15486==    by 0x11962C: updateClientStats (user_stats.c:623)
==15486==    by 0x1122E2: proccess_packet (proc_packets.c:55)
==15486==    by 0x111C4C: receive_client_data (net_server.c:524)
==15486==    by 0x1107E0: thread_waitNewClients (net_server.c:175)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't really see a problem within your code. I cannot identify any code paths where  `localini` or `error` are not freed. It might just be a memory leak in Glib, or some weird corner case where either `g_key_file_free` or `g_error_free` fails to deallocate. But imo that would also be internal to Glib. The only thing I can think of is that after the call to `g_key_file_load_from_file`, the value of `error` is not NULL. That would mean you need to `g_error_free(error);` before calling `g_key_file_get_int64`.

Comment: As an addition to the above, consider using g_autoptr and g_autofree if you can https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html (that is, if you know that your program will be compiled with either GCC or Clang). You can basically forget about all the places where to put free functions then. I once had 10 free function calls in a row somewhere before using these macros.

Comment: tks fanboy, I've tried with those macros, but still getting the same leak. Start thinking about a GLIB leak, not a real problem in my code :/. I also tried to use supression file from GLIBC, no changes in results, still with leak.